# regex for combination of number patterns

Tags: regex

I am attempting to write a regex that validates any of the following cases:

1. contains only 1 number  ex: 22
2. contains comma separated values ex: 1,22,28
3. contains range specified by using a hyphen ex: 5-9
4. contains a combination of all of the above.

I started to work with regex, but it does not work. Since I'm  a regex noob, I tried to write it out in the most verbose manner.

```
^[1-9]+|^[[[1-9]|[1-9\-1-9]],[[1-9]|[1-9\-1-9]]]+$
```

Can someone please help me with the regex that meets all the conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)*$
```

Comment: That does it! Altho' I did not mention in my question, I needed to validate for numbers > 0. So i just changed 0-9 to 1-9 in my regex. Thanks!